# How do I compile and run this Github project?

Tags: c#, github, building

https://github.com/Keegz51/CBIBFinal

There are no instructions to build/compile/run/use, and I'm unable to get it to run. I'm using the latest version of MS VS Code with C# Extension, please help!

Comment: Did you try compiling it in VS 2017? Did you contact https://github.com/Keegz51 for assistance?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow I'm afraid. We deal with specific and focused problems here but this is really just "please help me".

Answer (score 3):

You need to download the project

Install .NET Core (https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started-with-dotnet-tutorial)

Go to the root folder of the project (where .sln is located).

run 'dotnet restore' via a command line, terminal or powershell, it will install external packages

run 'dotnet run', it will launch the solution

or run 'dotnet build' if you just want to generate dll or exe from the project. On the command result, you'll find the path of the generation result.

You should install Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, it's easier to work with .NET Core

Comment: Ok will try this out

Comment: If you want to use debugger on visual studio code, you can click on "debug" (left toolbar)
Select add a configuration, it will take a launch.json file
If you click on the green arrow, debugger will be launched, and you will could put breakpoint (see visual studio code documentation)

Comment: So I've gone to the root folder of the project (where .sln is located), run 'dotnet restore' via command line, but when I run 'dotnet run' it gives an error "Couldn't find a project to run". Any idea how to fix this so the solution can be launched?

Comment: I need a previous version of .NET

Comment: Go on the project folder (where is located .csproj) or look thé command parameters to specify the name of the project

Comment: For the other version of. Net core, they all are available on the Website, download 1.1.2 if necessary

Comment: I managed to get it to run but now encountered the following error:

Comment: fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory[1]

Comment: An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.) --->

Comment: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Create another post